# Values get hardened

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two sets of data, one as a drop down (background orange) the second is an equation (background blue).  When I script to rest (erase the section) in the orange cells, they rest as expected.  HOWERVER, my blue cells change from the equation (ie:=E37) to the value, and I loose the equation.

Sample:

```
function ClearOrange() { //clears orange fields
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var color = sheet.getRange('D37').getBackground()
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var bgColors = range.getBackgrounds();
  var data = range.getValues()      
  for (var i=0; i<bgColors.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<bgColors[i].length; j++) {
      if (bgColors[i][j] == color) {
        data[i][j] = '';   
        // bgColors[i][j] = "#ffffff";//set to white         
      }
    }
  }
  range.setValues(data).setBackgrounds(bgColors);//reset values and backgrounds      
  }
```

Any advice?

Comment: try looping back : i--

Answer (score 0):

From your script and `HOWERVER, my blue cells change from the equation (ie:=E37) to the value, and I loose the equation.`, I guessed that the reason of your issue might be due to `var data = range.getValues()` and `range.setValues(data)`. In this case, the values except for the formulas are put into the cells. By this, the formulas are removed. In order not to remove the formulas, as a simple modification, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var data = range.getValues()      
for (var i=0; i<bgColors.length; i++) {
  for (var j=0; j<bgColors[i].length; j++) {
    if (bgColors[i][j] == color) {
      data[i][j] = '';   
      // bgColors[i][j] = "#ffffff";//set to white         
    }
  }
}
```

#### To

```
var data = range.getValues();
var formulas = range.getFormulas(); // Added
for (var i = 0; i < bgColors.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < bgColors[i].length; j++) {
    if (bgColors[i][j] == color) {
      data[i][j] = '';
    }
  }
}
formulas.forEach((r, i) => r.forEach((c, j) => { // Added
  if (c) data[i][j] = c;
}));
```

- By this modification, when the cell has the formula, the formula is kept instead of `""`.

#### Reference:

- [getFormulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformulas)

Comment: no that did not work, (it runs yes) the orange field clears but the blue field formula "=D34" in blue becomes the value "Arm" and the formula is still lost. ??

Comment: @user1742542 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your reply, I thought that in your situation, the cells except for `bgColors[i][j] == color` might have the formulas. For this situation, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? It that was not useful, I apologize again.